# High-Order ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, specifications, category-theory, scalacheck

Consider the following definition of a category:

```
trait Category[~>[_, _]] {
  def id[A]: A ~> A
  def compose[A, B, C](f: A ~> B)(g: B ~> C): A ~> C
}
```

Here's an instance for unary functions:

```
object Category {
  implicit def fCat = new Category[Function1] {
    def id[A] = identity
    def compose[A, B, C](f: A => B)(g: B => C) = g.compose(f)
  }
}
```

Now, categories are subject to some laws. Relating composition (`.`) and identity (`id`):

```
forall f: categoryArrow -> id . f == f . id == f
```

I want to test this with ScalaCheck. Let's try for functions over integers:

```
"Categories" should {
  import Category._

  val intG  = { (_ : Int) - 5 }

  "left identity" ! check {
    forAll { (a: Int) => fCat.compose(fCat.id[Int])(intG)(a) == intG(a) }      
  }

  "right identity" ! check {
    forAll { (a: Int) => fCat.compose(intG)(fCat.id)(a) == intG(a) }      
  }
}
```

But these are quantified over (i) a specific type (`Int`), and (ii) a specific function (`intG`). So here's my question: how far can I go in terms of generalizing the above tests, and how? Or, in other words, would it be possible to create a generator of arbitrary `A => B` functions, and provide those to ScalaCheck?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question, but it reminds me of the checks for the monad laws in scalaz. Perhaps you can take inspiration from https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/MonadTest.scala

Comment: perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral knows the answer ?

Comment: If the type is chosen arbitrarily then you could view this as universal quantification via Hilbert's epsilon. See https://gist.github.com/2659013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not knowing exactly with Hilbert's epsilon is, I would take a more fundamental approach and use ScalaCheck's [`Arbitrary`](http://scalacheck.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/1.9/doc/api/index.html#org.scalacheck.Arbitrary$) and [`Gen`](http://scalacheck.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/1.9/doc/api/index.html#org.scalacheck.Gen$) to select functions to use.

First, define a base class for the functions you are going to generate. In general, it's possible to generate functions that have undefined results (such as divide by zero), so we'll use [`PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) as our base class.

```
trait Fn[A, B] extends PartialFunction[A, B] {
  def isDefinedAt(a: A) = true
}
```

Now you can provide some implementations. Override `toString` so ScalaCheck's error messages are intelligible.

```
object Identity extends Fn[Int, Int] {
  def apply(a: Int) = a
  override def toString = "a"
}
object Square extends Fn[Int, Int] {
  def apply(a: Int) = a * a
  override def toString = "a * a"
}
// etc.
```

I've chosen to generate unary functions from binary functions using case classes, passing additional arguments to the constructor. Not the only way to do it, but I find it the most straightforward.

```
case class Summation(b: Int) extends Fn[Int, Int] {
  def apply(a: Int) = a + b
  override def toString = "a + %d".format(b)
}
case class Quotient(b: Int) extends Fn[Int, Int] {
  def apply(a: Int) = a / b
  override def isDefinedAt(a: Int) = b != 0
  override def toString = "a / %d".format(b)
}
// etc.
```

Now you need to create a generator of `Fn[Int, Int]`, and define that as the implicit `Arbitrary[Fn[Int, Int]]`. You can keep adding generators until you're blue in the face (polynomials, composing complicated functions from the simple ones, etc).

```
val funcs = for {
  b <- arbitrary[Int]
  factory <- Gen.oneOf[Int => Fn[Int, Int]](
    Summation(_), Difference(_), Product(_), Sum(_), Quotient(_),
    InvDifference(_), InvQuotient(_), (_: Int) => Square, (_: Int) => Identity)
} yield factory(b)

implicit def arbFunc: Arbitrary[Fn[Int, Int]] = Arbitrary(funcs)
```

Now you can define your properties. Use `intG.isDefinedAt(a)` to avoid undefined results.

```
property("left identity simple funcs") = forAll { (a: Int, intG: Fn[Int, Int]) =>
  intG.isDefinedAt(a) ==> (fCat.compose(fCat.id[Int])(intG)(a) == intG(a))
}

property("right identity simple funcs") =  forAll { (a: Int, intG: Fn[Int, Int]) =>
  intG.isDefinedAt(a) ==> (fCat.compose(intG)(fCat.id)(a) == intG(a))
}
```

While what I've shown only generalizes the function tested, hopefully this will give you an idea on how to use advanced type system trickery to generalize over the type.